# commander.js: fails trying to use a parameter named "options"

Tags: node.js, node-commander

I'm trying out commander.js for parsing arguments in my command-line tool, but it doesn't work properly when I use a parameter named `--options`:

```
// two params, both are optional
program
  .option('--api <apiYaml>')
  .option('--options <optionsYaml>')
  .parse(process.argv);

if (program.options) {
  let optionsFile = path.resolve(program.options);
  ...

if (program.api) {
  let apiFile = path.resolve(program.api);
  ...
```

This code works fine for the --api parameter, but dies when I call without an  --options parameter.

Adding some debug and looking at the `program` object, I see that the problem is that `program` already has an `options` property, as well as properties named `args`, `commands`, and `rawArgs`. Does that mean it's impossible to use any of those strings as parameters to my program, or is there a workaround? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: This is solved and documented from Commander v4.1, see https://github.com/tj/commander.js#avoiding-option-name-clashes